# Change dialogMessage color of EditTextPreference

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-preferences

I have a custom preference, which extends `EditTextPreference`:

```
class DeleteAccountPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : EditTextPreference(context, attrs) {
    ...
}
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<my.app.DeleteAccountPreference
    android:layout="@layout/preference_click"
    android:key="delete_account"
    android:title="Delete Account"
    android:dialogMessage="@string/delete_account_message" />
```

Which I have applied a custom theme to:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ...        
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorIcons</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorLightBlack</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorExit</item>
    <item name="editTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

[image]

However no matter what item I add to `AlertDialogTheme`, I can't seem to change the `dialogMessage` color (which is white) shown below.

Any idea what `<item>` I need to add to change this color?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use TextInputLayout inside DialogBox??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply `android:textColorSecondary` to the theme of your activity:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FF5722</item>
</style>
```

Then you'll get an orange message content:

[image]

Note, this will affect every other view in this activity, which relies on `textColorSecondary` attribute. I've tried to make this change affect only specific preference, unfortunately `PreferenceFragmentCompat` will disregard provided `Context` and will use context of the activity, hence passing around a `ContextThemeWrapper` with custom theme won't take effect. I guess this is a conscious decision from Google team, meaning that all of the attributes inside this preference screen should adapt to same color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following item into your AlertDialogStyle.

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Comment: That changes the color of the title (`DELETE ACCOUNT`), positive button (`OK`) and negative button (`CANCEL`). I only want to change the dialogMessage color (`Type Delete to delete your account`).